# Same logic code with same data type code passes in Java but not in C++?

Tags: java, c++, arrays, integer-overflow, subset-sum

I was solving a [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/description/) question where we have to find the number of set possible that adds to a target.

> Given an integer array with all positive numbers and no duplicates, find the number of possible combinations that add up to a positive integer target.

I wrote the code in Java

**JAVA**

```
class Solution {
    public int combinationSum4(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] dp = new int[target+1];
        dp[0] = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= target; i++){
            for(int num : nums){
                if(i >= num){
                    dp[i] += dp[i-num];
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[target];
    }
}
```

It passed all the test cases, but when I wrote the same code in C++. Its failing few of the test cases.

**C++**

```
class Solution {
public:
    int combinationSum4(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int dp[target+1] = {0};
        dp[0] = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= target; i++){
            for(int num : nums){
                if(i >= num){
                    dp[i] += dp[i-num];
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[target];
    }
};
```

The test case being :

```
nums : [3,33,333]
target : 10000
```

Error that I am getting :

```
Line 9: Char 27: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1941940377 + 357856184 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
```

**Note :** In the code I have only changed the declaration of dp array part as you can see. Why am I getting this error. Whats going wrong?

Comment: `int dp[target+1]` is a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). That's not C++ standard but at best a compiler extension. What about `std::vector<int> dp(target+1, 0);`?

Comment: `int dp[target+1] = {0};` is a VLA, which is not standard C++.   Some compilers support it as an extension.  `dp[i] += dp[i-num];`  gives undefined behaviour if `i - num` is not between `0` and `target` inclusive.    Consider what happens, for example, if `num` is negative.

Comment: @Peter I think thats another thing to think about -ve. currenty the OP i think wants to know why is it giving overflow for that testcase. I did try this on leetcode and indeed its giving an error but passing if using java

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar - That's trivial.   Signed integer overflow in Java wraps around (e.g. overflowing by adding two large values results in a negative value if the result would exceed the maximum the variable can represent).     Signed integer overflow in C++ has undefined behaviour - it is certainly not guaranteed to provide the same overflow behaviour as would occur in Java

Comment: @TedLyngmo Even `vector<int>` is not working for this test case on leetcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int` at leetcode seems to be 32 bits which can usually represent numbers in the range `[-2^31, 2^31)`.

Overflowing signed integers has undefined behaviour in C++. A signed 32 bit int have different representations on different platforms. You'll most often find the [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) version, but there are others.

```
                2^31-1 = 2147483647
1941940377 + 357856184 = 2299796561 // overflow error in C++
```

Add (if needed)

`#include <cstdint>`

and replace

`int dp[target+1] = {0};`

with

`std::vector<std::uintmax_t> dp(target+1, 0);`

`std::uintmax_t` gives you the largest unsigned integer type available and overflowing unsigned integers has a well defined behaviour in C++, so even if you do end up with a calculation larger than the limit, say 18446744073709551615 for a 64 bit integer, it will just wrap around. 18446744073709551615 + 1 == 0 in that case.

In Java, overflowing an int has well defined behaviour.
2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648
which is why you don't get in trouble when using that code in Java.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about `uintmax_t`, how is it helping here and why java int also has the same range `[-2^31, 2^31)` but its working totally fine

Comment: You shouldn't suggest the use of an unsigned type in expectation of overflows - except in code that causes them intentionally, which is not OP's case. `std::intmax_t` is a reasonable choice, but there is alternative to checking (or detecting) overflow and considering it explicitly.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica I didn't analyze OP:s algorithm that deeply but I thought that since it works with overflowing in Java and is limited to 32 bits there, making it unsigned and as large as possible would _probably_ avoid the problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

While @TedLyngmo's answer seems to have correctly identified the problem, I disagree about the solution.

You should not just ignore overflow, even if its behavior *is* well defined. The coding problem you were given is in itself flawed, as, indeed, the number of possible additive decompositions of an integer increases exponentially with the value of that integer, meaning the size of the output is at least some linear function of the value of the input number - and that means any fixed-size type will be inappropriate.

If you actually wanted to solve this problem and produce correct output without overflow, you would need a "big int" class - something which can hold arbitrarily-large values.

Here's an example C++ BigInt implementation:

https://github.com/kasparsklavins/bigint

There are others, of course (but there isn't one in the standard library).